# Trying to access specific id in another page by the [id].svelte route in svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am trying to show the details of my airtable content in another page based of id.
This is my file structure:

[image: structure of files]

On my about page(yes I used svelte kit to create my app.) I called the api and I'm looping through it. I can see my test content and its working fine:

```html
onMount(() => {
    fetch("https://api.airtable.com/v0/apikey/etc", {
      method: "get",
      headers: new Headers({ Authorization: "Bearer apikey" }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        records = data.records;
        console.log(records[1].fields.Name);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
```

And I'm looping through it:

```html
  {#each records as record, i}
    <a href={`/listOfStuff/${record.id}`}>{record.id}</a>
    <p>{record.fields.Name}</p>
  {/each}
```

So in my [id].js I tried to load specific data by doing this.I tried accessing the id parameter:

```
   let id=$page.params.id;
```

Then tried loading the data:

```html
 onMount(() => {
      fetch("https://api.airtable.com/v0/apikey/etc"+id, {
        method: "get",
        headers: new Headers({ Authorization: "Bearer apikey" }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          records = data.records;
          console.log(records[1].fields.Name);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  </script>
```

```html
 onMount(() => {
      fetch("https://api.airtable.com/v0/apikey/Names"+id, {
        method: "get",
        headers: new Headers({ Authorization: "Bearer apikey" }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          records = data.records;
          console.log(records[1].fields.Name);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Then tried accessing it:

```html
{#each records as record, i}
<p>{record.id}</p>
<p>{record.fields.Name}</p>
{/each}
```

But when I try navigating to it from my about page and click on the href I dont see anything loading afterwards. The route takes me to the route of the specific id but the page itself is blank. That's why I am very confused.
Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your API endpoints for getting the record of a specific ID are right? It looks like you took the endpoint access from your list page and randomly slapped on an ID at the end... Also, why are there 2 different endpoints? Figure out the ONE correct endpoint you should be using, make sure the request format is correct, and customize your method to handle the response format (which will probably be a bit different than the one you received in your list page). I recommend using a tool like Postman to test and get familiar with endpoints before implementing them in your code.

Comment: Sorry my issue ended up actually being a typo. Its a bit embarrassing....considering it took me hours to figure that out. Sorry about that.

Comment: Don't be embarrassed, everybody makes mistakes ;) Think instead about what you can do to prevent these mistakes from happening or identify them quickly when they happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in the link. That was the issue. I'm sorry it took me too long to realize it.